# Using ConcurrentBag instead of Arrays (multithreading)

Tags: .net, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

I have an array that is periodically being accessed by multiple threads approx each second (one writer thread and one or two readers).

After searching, I initially thought of using "Lock" or "Monitor" statements to protect the critical code (As I understand the critical code in my case is the one that writes to the array).

Then I found that .Net 4.x introduced new [Concurrent Collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent(v=vs.110).aspx) which seemed to me that it suits my need here.

So instead of using an array, I'll use ConcurrentBag just for the sake of safe-threading. Do you agree with me that the small overhead cost of using this List (ConcurrentBag) does worth it? or do you recommend other collection?

Note: I'll not need any sorting, dynamic re-sizing or any other operation on this array\list. It'll be a fixed-length and will need it for read and write

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Impossible to day without seeing more details of what you are doing. You also need to synchronize reads if you are writing to the same data concurrently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually I'd go for "use the readily available concurrent classes" because they are well-designed and thoroughly tested and better suite most use cases than any self-made multithreading solutions.

But as you ask for a simple solution without any need for dynamic resizing, just go for the `lock` statement (which, by the way, is using the `Monitor` class behind the scenes).

Be careful, as this

> As I understand the critical code in my case is the one that writes to the array.

is not true. Critical code in your case, and in most other cases, is any code that accesses shared resources, be it reading or writing.

Best practice would probably be something like this:

```
private object syncLock = new object();
private string[] yourArray = whatever;

private void ThisMethodReads()
{
    ...
    lock (this.syncLock)
    {
        // Read from the array.
    }
    ...
}

private void ThisMethodReadsAndWrites()
{
    ...
    lock (this.syncLock)
    {
        // Read from and/or write to the array.
    }
    ...
}
```

To get a better understanding of multithreading issues and their solutions, I usually recommend [Joe Albahari's multithreading tutorial](http://www.albahari.com/threading/).

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. The reason I'm trying to use one of the "readily available concurrent classes" instead of "Lock" statement is to eliminate the possibility of any threading issues like dead-locks.

Comment: In addition, I understand that "readerwriterlockslim" can be used for the writing part only and eliminates the need to "lock" the reading code. Am I correct?

Comment: In theory, yes. In practice, you told you would call the code once every second or so. Depending on how long your code takes to execute, you just don't need it. Use ReaderWriterLockSlim only if you have lots of (really many) parallel reads and only some sporadic writes. Google for performance comparisons.

Comment: Well, the "Write" is also per-second. Basically, this array\list holds values that are obtained from hardware (here's the "Write" part) and these values will be used in many uses such as calculations, checks, storing to DB, make it available for remote clients via WCF (here are the "Reads" part). This is just to simply the application, obtaining data from the hardware will also be using threads, but each thread will affect unique specific parts of the array so I guess this part is OK and need no threadsafe handling.